How to capture frames from video stream platforms (Netflix)?
I have some troubles while extracting frames from encrypted video streams using javascript. Could be some platforms such as Netflix,...
I've used html5 canvas and createStream() API but when I capture a frame from video and turn into base64 string, it becomes a black screen because the video stream is encrypted. If the video stream is not encrypted then it works as expected.
Many video streaming services use DRM (Digital Rights Management) technologies to prevent the browser from accessing the video content directly. So it's quite hard to capture a frame image from any platform using DRM using standard HTML5 apis.
Do you guys have any ideas how can I capture those frames via Client side (Javascript) or maybe Server side?
Thanks for any help!
